# Laravel 5 and models

Tags: laravel

I have a new installation of Laravel 5. The problem is that it's not recognizing my model classes. I will keep it very simple for solution purposes.

```
Route::get('test', function() {
    $test = boxstyle::all(); 
    ....
}
```

My model is in the app directory

```
<?php namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class Boxstyle extends Model  {  
    protected $table = 'boxstyle';
    protected $primaryKey = 'key1';
}
```

I am getting:

```
class boxstyle not found error
```

I've been searching all over the internet and can't find a solution. This installation is fresh. This isn't magic and I suspect a configuration issue but I can't find a solution. This works fine in Laravel 4.2 so I know it should work but not working in L5.

Comment: **b**oxstyle != **B**oxstyle

Answer (score 0):

Your model is defined inside the `App` namespace.  If the code accessing the model is not in the same namespace as the model, you need to qualify it.

```
Route::get('test', function() {
    $test = \App\Boxstyle::all();
}
```

Laravel 4 did not define the models and controllers inside namespaces. Your models would have been defined inside the global namespace, so any code also in the global namespace (like your controller) would not need to qualify the model. However, Laravel 5 has made the push to put most everything inside namespaces.

Answer (score 0):

To create a model in Laravel 5 try this,create a folder name "Models" folder under your App folder, now for instance you want to create a Model class for Boxstyle ...under your Models folder create a file name 
"BoxstyleModel.php" inside your BoxstyleModel.php should look like this and make sure your inside the folder to namespace your model under the App\Models

`<?php namespace App\Models;`

`use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;`
`class BoxstyleModel extends Model {`

```
public static function say_hello(){
    return "Hello";
}
```

`}`

in your Boxstyle Controller to be able to use your BoxstyleModel added this code at the top of your BoxstyleController `use App\Models\BoxstyleModel;`

now everything should be the same like Laravel 4.X.